# Problema de router link React JS, no puedo redireccionar un botón

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Intento redireccionar un botón desde la página de productos, en este caso el botón lo redirecciono con Link, pero no me manda a ningún lado, en mi archivo de router ya lo agregé y no me funciona tampoco.

Este es mi botón dentro de products.

```
<Link to="/add" className="link btn btn-primary col-sm-2 float-right">Add Product</Link>
```

y este es mi archivo router.js

```
import React from 'react';
        const List = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Products/list'));
        const Add = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Products/Add/add'));
        const Edit = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Products/edit'));

    const routes = [
     { path: '/products/list', name: 'List', component: List },
      { path: '/products/add/add', name: 'Add', component: Add },
      { path: '/products/edit', name: 'Edit', component: Edit },

    ];
```

he seguido varios tutoriales, y no me funciona ninguno, en otro proyecto de prueba, si me direcciona así, pero no uso un archivo de routes.js, en este otro simplemente importo directamente en el index las rutas que voy a usar, y me funciona, ya probé importando directamente pero tampoco me funciona.

todo esto lo estoy probando dentro de una plantilla admin-dashboard que conseguí, siempre redirecciona al index cuando apreto cualquiero botón.

Comment: por tal como tienes las rutas no deberías ser `to='/products/add/add'` en vez de solo `/add` en el `Link`

Comment: olvidé comentar que también lo tenía así y no funciona, fue que al probar olvidé volverlo a como estaba.

Comment: @JoséLuisMolinaCascante por favor puedes completar tu pregunta poniendo la parte en que utilizar `Router`?